# Specific Month-day select statement query

Tags: sql

I would like to select from a table where the date falls within a specific time each year f.e:

```
select * from Customer where date >= August 15th and date <= December 20th
```

Since this will be for a report that runs every year, I do not want to hardcore the date as I will have to change it every year. I would like to have it dynamic to pick the date from August 15th to December 20th of the current year.

I have the below query where I can retrieve the Month and Date:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, date) AS Month,DATENAME(day, date) AS Day from Customer
```

However, I am struggling to have this selection date range.

TIA

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ... Date functions and operators differ a lot in different DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL SERVER 2017
maybe this can help you:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE date BETWEEN 
CONVERT(DATETIME,CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()),'08','15')) AND 
CONVERT(DATETIME,CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()),'12','20'))
```

This add the current year to a concatenated date you want, then convert it all into datetime type..